# unable to save data to local MongoDB (React native)

Tags: mongodb, react-native

I am trying to use local MongoDB for the case when users don't have internet access. The real-time data is stored on firebase. When I tried to save the firebase data to the local MonogoDB, I got an error that mongoose.connect is not a function. Here is the code.

Aims to have a MongoDB database come along with the App, so that the client can get the data even there is no internet. How could I implement the save data to local MonogoDB in react native app? Thanks for your help!

```
class writeDataToMonogo extends React.component{
      ..........
      insertData(){
         const mongoose = require('mongoose');
         const url = 'mongodb://.........';
         mongoose.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true});
         const conn = mongoose.connection;
         conn.on('connected', function() {
              console.log('database is connected successfully');
             });
         conn.on('disconnected',function(){
               console.log('database is disconnected successfully');
              })
         conn.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
         ....
```

Comment: import mongoose from "mongoose"; hope you have included?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose is used on the server side to connect to mongodb.
You should not use it directly from react native.
Therefore, if the client has no internet access it won't be able to reach any server.
If you want to store offline data for later use, try using AsyncStorage:
https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage